# Git Repo recovery

Tags: git, github, backup, recovery

I will try to explain my situation the best I can.

I had to format my computer (Mac mini / running mavericks). Later, while I'm resorting the backup I realized my last project isn't there.

Does someone know how can I recover the project ? I was using git on my computer but I didn't push the repo (sadly). I don't know if that gives me any kind of advantage to recover the files.

I'm really lost here... don't know what to do!

Thanks

Comment: If you had / can recover the working copy (the folder where you had your versiones repo), then it's trivial. If you can't, then I'm afraid it isn't a git question.

Comment: If it wasn't pushed, it doesn't exist in the eyes of git anymore. It's not different from any other file at this point.

Comment: That's what I thought @amenadiel . However, I'm not so sure if I'm able to recover it. So far, no luck  with that... That's why I was trying to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the kind of reformat, tools (like for instance [Yodot Mac Data Recovery](http://www.yodot.com/mac-data-recovery/after-accidental-format.html) not free, but there are others) *might* be able to recover those files.
If the [Time Machine partition wasn't erased, the git repo might be there too](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110272).

But other than that, a git repo is just a collection of files, and wouldn't be any more or less recoverable than any other group of files.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I used 3 different softwares to restore the data. The only one that found the folder was [Stellar Phoenix Data Recovery](http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-data-recovery.htm?gclid=CMag_P_Gn8ACFQQT7AodTn8AvA). However, to actually restore the files you have to pay the license. I will try with Yodot